# qemu-system-arm: -M raspi2 can't support USB input

Tags: ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi, qemu, emulation

I have a problem launching Ubuntu Mate startup in qemu-arm.
Here we have `qemu-3.0.0` with `libusb`.
I installed it with

```
$ ./configure
$ make install
$ cd arm-sofmmu
```

Here is the `qemu` command line input:

```
$ sudo qemu-system-arm -M raspi2 -kernel /mnt/kernel7.img -append "$(cat /mnt/cmdline.txt)" -drive file=/media/alireza/62DCD1493FEA67A0/mate.img,if=sd,format=raw -m 1024 -cpu cortex-r5 -dtb /mnt/bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4" -usb -device usb-mouse,bus=002,vendorid=0x1d6b,productid=0x0004 -smp 4
```

and here is the output:

```
$ qemu-system-arm: -device usb-mouse,bus=002,vendorid=0x1d6b,productid=0x0004: Bus '002' not found
```

I have this USB device and I want to capture it:

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 09da:000a A4Tech Co., Ltd. Optical Mouse Opto 510D / OP-620D
```

How do I fix this?
My `libusb` status is `= yes` in `./configure`.
But I am using another USB input `-usbdevice` then using this and this is my output:

```
qemu-system-arm: -usbdevice mouse: '-usbdevice' is deprecated, please use      '-device usb-...' instead
qemu-system-arm: -usbdevice mouse: Error: no usb bus to attach usbdevice mouse, please try -machine usb=on and check that the machine model supports USB
qemu-system-arm: -usbdevice mouse: could not add USB device 'mouse'
```

I have Tired with adding an USB device to `qemu-arm -M raspi2`.
How do I add the USB device in `qemu-arm -M raspi2`?

Answer (score 1):

Qemu does not emulate the rpi usb controller yet: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1772165.

If you need to emulate the rpi hardware you're out of luck, otherwise you can get/compile a kernel for `versatilepb`, like here: https://github.com/wimvanderbauwhede/limited-systems/wiki/Raspbian-%22stretch%22-for-Raspberry-Pi-3-on-QEMU

Comment: Yeah its fixed with vexpress-a15, this guy fixed my question, actually my question is: how i emulate raspberry pi 2/3 ((ARMv7)) series with qemu, hopefully its fixed with vexpress!: [https://github.com/vfdev-5/qemu-rpi2-vexpress]

Answer (score 0):

the emulation of raspberry pi with versatile with `qemu` is not a good idea, because its actually emulation of raspberry pi 0/1 "ARMv6" Series, & i didn't like it, for best answer of working mouse & keyboard, you can emulate raspberry pi 2/3 "ARMv7" Series with vexpress-a15 or a9, this guy fix your problem: "but, you have experience super slow emulation."
https://github.com/vfdev-5/qemu-rpi2-vexpress